# Updating the image property of an object each timer tick C#

Tags: c#, winforms, graphics

I have a sprite class which has a draw method which draws an explosion.
The class has an image property which is used as the image that will be drawn.

I wish to have it so that the image that is draw is changed every 5 seconds or so.

My question is: Using a timer control, how can I code it so the Image property is changed to a different image each tick?

For example, Image 1 '5 seconds' > Image 2 '5 seconds' > Image 3 '5 seconds' > remove image.

Here is the draw method:

```
    public void DrawExplosion(Graphics graphics)
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(explosion_, xPos_, yPos_);
    }
```

and the Image property of the class

```
    public Image Explosion
    {
        get {return explosion_;}
        set {explosion_ = value;}
    }
```

Thanks for any help/guidance.

Comment: What do you think your Timer event handler looks like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i noticed my answer was far to complex for the simple question asked.  While I don't believe it is incorrect I do think it complicates the matter.  I wanted to leave it there in case someone else finds it useful.  But here is a simplified attempt.  It uses a timer external to the Sprite class, a button and a panel.  I hope this is helpful.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControl
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Sprites Explosion = new Sprites();


    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //insert your images in this next line
        Explosion.Images=new Image[]{Properties.Resources.explode1,Properties.Resources.explode2,Properties.Resources.explode3};
        Explosion.ImageIndex = 0;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
        //Draw the first image right away
        Explosion.Draw(panel1.CreateGraphics(), 0, 0);
        //set the index to the next image
        Explosion.ImageIndex++;
    }


    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //if the Imageindex is not greater then the number of images
        if (Explosion.ImageIndex < Explosion.Images.Count() )
        {
            Explosion.Draw(panel1.CreateGraphics(), 0, 0);
            Explosion.ImageIndex++;
        }
        //if it is greater then reset the imageIndex and turn off the timer
        else
        {
            Explosion.ImageIndex = 0;
            timer1.Enabled = false;
            //Clear your images, however you need to do that
            panel1.CreateGraphics().Clear(Color.White);
        }


    }
}


public class Sprites
{
    public Image DisplayedImage { get { return Images[ImageIndex]; } }
    public int ImageIndex;
    public Image[] Images;

    public void Draw(Graphics graphics, int x, int y)
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(DisplayedImage, x, y);
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If my guess is correct and you're writing a game then you probably don't want a timer here. There are a lot of articles on programming game loops which would fit your scenario.

They basically separate the logical update of your screen elements (here, a sprite) from their rendering and use OS hooks to keep the performance high.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT:  I added another answer below.  I found this answer to complicated for the question asked.

JRoughan Might be correct there might be better ways to do this.  But as per your request I wrote an class that will take images you supply and draw them one at a time onto a graphics object then clear the graphics object.

I instantiated the Class within a Method, so there is no guarantee it wont go out of scope and get collected before running fully, to prevent this you might want to have make it global, then just re instantiate it every time you want to use it, with new images.  But if you call it twice, the first one will be loss so I found this method better, it depends on the context, how many different animations you're planning to use at once etc...  I also added a ImageindexChanged event that can be used to know when the image changes outside of the class.  Enjoy!  I hope this is what your looking for.

I just added a button and a panel.  tying the buttons click event into the Button1_Click method

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace CustomControl
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        //insert your images in this next line
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Image[] explodingImages = new Image[] { Properties.Resources.explode1, Properties.Resources.explode2, Properties.Resources.explode3 };
        //initialize the explosion with the images from above
        Sprites Explosion = new Sprites(explodingImages,panel1.CreateGraphics());
        //the timer will start and it will draw all images from the above collection, then clear itself, then dispose of itself.
        Explosion.ImageIndex = 0;
    }

}


public class Sprites
{
    private Image _DisplayedImage;
    public Image DisplayedImage
    {
        get { return _DisplayedImage; } 
    }
    private Image[] Images{get;set;}
    private int _ImageIndex = 0;

    public event EventHandler ImageIndexChanged;

    public int ImageIndex
    {
        get { return _ImageIndex; }
        set
        {
            //Changes thh ImageIndexNumber
            _ImageIndex = value;
            //Updates the Displayed Image with the current Image as per index
            _DisplayedImage = Images[ImageIndex];
            //fires the ImageIndexChanged Event (if required)
            if (ImageIndexChanged != null)
                ImageIndexChanged(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            //draws the explosion to the graphics object
            DrawExplosion(G, 0, 0);
            //starts the timer
            changeImageTimer.Enabled = true;
        }
    }
    //local variable for the graphics object
    private Graphics G;
    //creats a timer for changing the Images
    Timer changeImageTimer = new Timer();
    //Constructor
    public Sprites(Image[] images,Graphics g)
    {
        //set the starting Images
        Images = images;
        //set the interval time to 5 seconds- in my opinion this number is rediculously high, but if that is what you want
        changeImageTimer.Interval = 5000;
        //Get the Tick event of the timer
        changeImageTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(changeImageTimer_Tick);
        //set the Graphics that you want to draw on
        G = g;
    }

    void changeImageTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int temp=ImageIndex+1;
        //if there are no more pictures to display stop the timer
        if (temp > Images.Count() - 1)
        {
            //stop the timer
            changeImageTimer.Enabled = false;
            //Clear the image, replace with your own background color, or draw an image or whatever you need to do to clear the images
            G.Clear(Color.White);
        }
        //if there are more pictures select the next picture
        else
            //Changeing the imageindex fires the draw method and the imageindexchanged event
            ImageIndex++;
    }

    public void DrawExplosion(Graphics graphics,int x, int y)
    {
        graphics.DrawImage(DisplayedImage, x, y);
    }
}
}
```